# Storing allocated value to allocated array

Tags: c, memory-management, malloc, dynamic-memory-allocation

The code I have is this:

```
uint8_t* payload = (uint8_t*)malloc(payload_size);
uint8_t* payloads = (uint8_t*)malloc(payload_size * 100);

for(uint8_t i = 0; i < 100; i++ ){

create_payload(payload); //cannot modify 

//myapproach
payloads[i] = payload;

}
```

And this is not even compiling.

I'd like to store the payload values to the payloads array because the payload variable gets replaced at every iteration.

Is there a simple solution to this?

Comment: `payloads` seems to be an array of pointers, so don't you need `uint8_t** payloads = (uint8_t**)malloc(payload_size * 100);`? If so, there's one more question, `payload` allocated only once, why?

Comment: What does `create_payload` return/take? What is its signature like?

Comment: `payloads[i] = *payload;` You need to dereference it since payload is a pointer, but you probably want to store the value, not the pointer.

Comment: @user3365922 because, as far as I understand it, the value gets replaced.

Comment: @Ayxan it does not return anything, it takes a uint8_t

Comment: @churill what do you mean? that storing it into an array won't work?

Comment: You have a pointer `payload`. Do you want to store that pointer or do you want to store the value it is pointing to? If you want to store the value, you need to dereference the pointer first.

Comment: @Mattia Show a minimal complete program that demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first, `payloads` should point to pointers of `uint8_t`, not a `uint8_t` itself (Because you want to store pointers on this data)

Then, you using same buffer for every payload creation, so you filling payloads with pointer to the same data, you need to allocate new buffer for every payload

And, at last - size of resulting buffer will be

```
size of one entry *pointer* * count of entries
```

not a

```
size of one entry * count of entries
```

So resulting code will be:

```c
uint8_t** payloads = (uint8_t**)malloc(sizeof(uint8_t*) * 100);
// uint8_t* payloads[100]; - Will also work

for(uint8_t i = 0; i < 100; i++ ){
    uint8_t* payload = (uint8_t*)malloc(payload_size);

    create_payload(payload); //cannot modify 

    payloads[i] = payload;
}
```

Or, if you wanted to have all payloads to be in same buffer, use `malloc` to copy payload to output:

```c
uint8_t* payload = (uint8_t*)malloc(payload_size);
uint8_t* payloads = (uint8_t*)malloc(payload_size * 100);

for(uint8_t i = 0; i < 100; i++ ){

    create_payload(payload); //cannot modify 

    memcpy(payloads + i * payload_size, payload, payload_size);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make an array of type `uint8_t` pointer:

```
uint8_t* payloads[100];
```

then set an element of that array to a payload pointer you have:

```
payloads[i] = payload;
// make sure payload is of type uint8_t pointer
```